# How to align rear v brakes

Tags: brakes, alignment

i have a bike that has v brakes on the rear wheel. Everytime i try to align the brakes after i ride and use a few times the rear brakes, one of the pads is rubbing on the rim. Please help as i have spent a lot of hours on it without gain anything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One of the likely culprits is that you've put too much spring tension in on the arms. Start by loosening the spring tension on the arms, adjusting the brake and then increasing to just enough tension.

[These](http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/linear-pull-brake-service-v-brake-type) [links](http://sheldonbrown.com/canti-direct.html) will be useful.

Comment: The spring tension can also be uneven.  If it's always rubbing on the same side, try loosening that side, or tightening the other side.

Comment: Yeah - but thats generally linked to being too sensitive when you cant afjust it cause the tension is too high.